# How should resolvconf handle multiple interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: 14.04, networking, 16.04, dns

I'm on a fresh Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS and at installation I assigned it `address 192.168.0.151`, `dns-nameservers 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.11` and `dns-search example.com`.

So after installation and reboot I got `/etc/network/interfaces` with this content:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.0.151
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.11
    dns-search example.com
```

And `/etc/resolv.conf` as:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.100.10
nameserver 192.168.100.11
search favoptic.com
```

This is all OK and works as expected! But now I want to add 2 [vip-addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address) (Virtual IP address or *aliases*), so I add the following to `/etc/network/interfaces` without changing any of the things already present (just adding):

```
auto ens18:0
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.0.152
    netmask 255.255.255.0

auto ens18:1
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.0.153
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

After reboot I now got 3 working ip's on the host.

**BUT now `/etc/resolv.conf` is *empty***, only this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

So dns resolution does not work any more. Ex:

```
$ ping askubuntu.com
ping: unknown host askubuntu.com
```

I have another host installed with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, and I have similar setup of interfaces and ip's there and it all works flawlessly!

---

**Solution**

If I add `dns-nameservers` and `dns-search` to both of the vip-definitions it will work, but it seems to be a bit redundant. Is this a bug or designed this way just to puzzle me?

Comment: I found the same. I had dns-search on one interface (eth0) but not the other (wlan0).  On reboot, about 10% of the time or less did I get the correct info in /etc/resolv.conf. Rest of the time it was empty. So I've now added dns-search to both and it seems happy now.